# Fast efficient way to split this string and get the gun names

Tags: python, pandas, regex

what is a really fast and efficient way to extract out the gun names from this string?

0::223 Rem [AR-15]||1::44 Mag

I've coded splits and then for loops on those splits, so first I split the string by ||, then for each split item, I split again on :: and then on each one I split on space ' ' and then take the item = 1 from there.

There must be a simpler way to do this?  My way seems clumsy and novice.

```
 gun_item = item.split('||')
gun_type = gun_item.split('::')[1]
gun_name = gun_type.split(' ')
```

Comment: Update your question with a code block containing the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Just updated with the code I have so far.  I got to thinking the faster way is to only extract the non-numbers and non-special characters.

Comment: What is the expected result ? Also show several items (necessary to understand the exact format ).

Comment: You should [edit] to include your expected output, as "extract out the gun names" is only clear to someone who knows which part of your string is a gun name

Answer (score 1):

I used regex to find the name following the "numbers::numbers " pattern.

```
import re 

gun_string = "0::223 Rem [AR-15]||1::44 Mag"

re.findall("\d*::\d* (?P<gun>\w*)", gun_string)
```

Comment: Haven't done regex in a long time, ah this makes sense.  If the data is in a certain format, then I just set the regex to that format.  This is a really great foolproof way to do it.  Thanks!!

Comment: By the way, I see your profile says you're a data scientist.  Do you use regex often when scrubbing/pre-processing data?

Comment: Not that often, just another random tool in my toolbelt. Also, fyi, you can use https://regex101.com/ to test out your patterns.

Comment: It is not so common I guess especially when data has been cleaned from UI layer. Just took at look at the link and tried out the regex from here.  This is a great tool thank you!

Comment: You could make the quantifiers 1 or more times to match at least a digit and a gun name instead of possibly an empty string `\d::\d+ (?P<gun>\w+)`